# Filtering a query using a case statement that returns a list of possible values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change the filter based on a value, the code would look like this if this was valid syntax:

```
SELECT
    Value
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    ID IN (CASE WHEN <expression> THEN (1,2,3) ELSE (1,2) END)
```

So I want to select a value, and the filter changes based on some expression. When the expression is true, I want to select all values with an ID of 1, 2, or 3. When the expression is false, I want to select all values with an ID of only 1 or 2.

It's not a straightforward `=` but selecting from a list of values which is why it doesn't work. How is this achievable?

Comment: can you show what your `<expression>` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Simple logic is sufficient:

```
WHERE (<expression> and ID IN (1, 2, 3)) or
      (not <expression> and ID IN (1, 2))
```

In this case, you can simplify this to:

```
where id in (1, 2) or
      (id = 3 and <expression>)
```